# Confused on Deitel's wording in regards to highest-priority element in a priority queue

Tags: java, collections, queue, priority-queue

I'm currently reading the Java How to program book by Deitel and some of the wording seems to be confusing.  I'm wondering if someone can explain this as it seems to be misleading.

> When adding elements to a PriorityQueue, the elements are inserted in priority order such that the highest-priority element (i.e., the largest value) will be the first element removed from the PriorityQueue.

The part that confuses me is where it says that the highest-priority element (largest value) will be removed.  Based on that statement, if I were to add 9.8, 5.4, and 3.2 in a one PriorityQueue, then I would expect it to delete/poll the PriorityQueue in that order, regardless of what order I had placed them in when I inserted them.

However, during my code example, I noticed the opposite.  The order in which the elements were removed were by the smallest amount first.  When reading the javadocs, I see where it says "The head of this queue is the least element with respect to the specified ordering", which is consistent with what I had found working with the code example.

Does this mean that the book is wrong, or am I just not grasping the wording that the book is using to describe this concept?

Comment: He's wrong and the Javadoc is correct. You can however define a `Comparator` that reverses the order.

Answer (score 0):

"Largest value" is some careless wording.

Priority queues can return elements according to potentially any ordering scheme (as they accept custom comparators), but by default, they return elements according to their "natural order." In Java, lower numbers come "before" larger numbers.

You can take a look at natural orderings for some major classes (including the wrappers for each of the primitives) in the Oracle docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html